# What is the logic in the java stars program?

Tags: java, logic

I found a program on the internet for printing a pattern of stars-

```
public class Stars
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<=i; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

And now I am trying really hard to understand the logic behind this program. Of course, I know the looping control structure but, the thing due to which I am struggling is that how is the * related to the variables. Is there something like the inner loop is executed 'i' times? Pls sort out my problem I am struggling really hard to understand this program.
And also pls pardon me if this question is a silly one because as I told in the profile I am still just a student studying in 8th class. I don't have much knowledge. Thanks : )

Comment: Did you run this program?

Comment: If you look closely, the condition in the second loop is `j <= i`. It will repeat `i + 1` times.

Comment: Omg thanks u replied : )

Comment: They're just nested for loops... [check this out](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_for_loop.asp) if you don't know how to use for loops.

Comment: O yeah u are right thank u so much I was struggling on this problem : )

Comment: thank u so much it sorts out my problem : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a double loop in which the first loop is executed 5 times. At the beginning the first loop variable starts with i=0 and the second loop with j=0. The second loop will execute untill the i<=j so 1 time at the first loop.
The first loop then restarts, with i=1 and the second loop also restarts but from the beginning j=0 and will execute two times because first j=0 and is <= than i=1 and then j=1 and is <= then i=1. And so on. At the end of each inner loop this code print a new line character.

Comment: Hmm oh ok thanks i get it :)

Comment: i cannot accept the answer lol thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is known as nested for loop in java.

in your case:---

```
when i=0 , j=0
```

second for loop will repeat once and prints once "* ". cursor will go to next line.

```
when i=1  then j=0,1
```

second for loop will repeat twice and prints  "* * ". cursor will go to next line.

similarly

```
when i=4 then j= 0,1,2,3,4
```

second for loop will repeat 5 times and prints  "* * * * * ". cursor will go to next line.

```
So final o/p will be
    i=0..... i=4
j=0 * 
j=1 * * 
j=2 * * *
j=3 * * * *
j=4 * * * * *
```